# Is there a way to connect Apache airflow with Superset?

Tags: visualization, airflow, apache-superset

Can we connect Superset with Airflow? So that when a task gets completed, Airflow can trigger the Superset to fetch the data from a data source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Superset is a visualization tool which can display dashboards for multiple database types. While Airflow is a orchestration tool to manage job.

What Airflow can do is to ask the task to fetch data into database where Superset can consume.